# android gradle build: Generated class list does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dagger-2

When I try to build my android app in android studio 2.3.2 this single error occures:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':viewmodel:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease'.
> failure, see logs for details.
Generated class list does not exist MyPath\viewmodel\build\intermediates\data-binding-info\release\_generated.txt
```

The folder is empty indeed and I'm building this whole thing on debug, not release (But also debug is empty).

I'm using dagger (2.10) for dependency injection, which may be the source of this problem, but I couldn't really find any help on the internet for this error.

The gradle.build file for this module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    def rootConfig = rootProject.ext

    compileSdkVersion rootConfig.androidCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootConfig.androidBuildToolsVersion

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootConfig.androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootConfig.androidTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootConfig.applicationVersionCode
        versionName rootConfig.applicationVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //include appDependencies
    def appDependencies = rootProject.ext.appDependencies

    //compile jars,...
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //compile other projects
    compile project(':mvvmbase')
    compile project(':logic')
    compile project(':model')
    compile project(':utility')

    //compile appDependencies
    compile appDependencies.appCompat
    compile appDependencies.dagger
    apt appDependencies.daggerCompiler
    provided appDependencies.javaxAnnotation

    //TestCompile
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile appDependencies.testCompile
}
```

Comment: I believe something is wrong with Dagger 2 configuration. Could you double-check it?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't databinding? I've always had intermittent issues with it, normally you have to clean rebuild and cross your fingers.

Comment: I removed android-apt as suggested in another post i found. But now I'm stuck to the stupid cannot find symbol variable DaggerServicesComponents error again. And clean and then building the project doesn't help...

Comment: Can you please [edit] to include your  `appDependencies` and your updated `build.gradle` after removing apt?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in a library, because I was using

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

without the kapt dependency

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0'
```

(Note: *kapt* is for Kotlin, for Java you can use *apt* or *annotationProcessor* depending on the Gradle version you are using.)

Comment: Please also note you need to enable the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin in your project, e.g. `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`. More details are available here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html.